# Is there a recommended font and size for a job application?

Tags: faculty-application, formatting

Is there a recommended font and size for academic job application? Usually I see Times New Roman being used with a 10 point font size for research papers, but I don't think that it is the best font and size for reading.  Can I pick a font that I prefer, or is there some "best practices" that people expect and I should follow?

Comment: I'd go for a sans serif font. There's a good chance it will be read on screen, and going sans will make it much easier for the reader. Just no Arial or Helvetica, make it something a bit more elegant.

Comment: Well, what do you think is the best font and size?  See [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71172/why-are-default-latex-margins-so-big) for a discussion on font size/margins.

Comment: Vote to close, I think this is a case of boat programming (or boat academics).

Comment: I think this question should be ask in Graphic Design

Comment: @Michael: depending on the field, a sans serif font may stand out. The vast majority of applications I have seen in math used a serif font, usually Computer Modern, Times New Roman, or Palatino.

Comment: I tend to disagree with the point of this topic being an opinion. There should be a reason why most applications are using Times New Roman. However, would using something else like Arial, Calibiri etc, considered not professional?

Comment: I have fixed the question to not be the opinion-based "What is?" but instead the "Is there a right choice?" matching the accepted answer ("no"), and am voting to reopen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It really doesn't matter what font you choose, as long as it's not unprofessional.  You can safely choose any font you might use for a research paper, 10 to 12 points in size (preferably 11 or 12, for the benefit of those with poor eyesight, but 10 is OK).  It's not worth worrying about this too much.  You can't help your chances through elegant typography, and the only way you can hurt them is if you do something ridiculous.  Any effects on readability are probably small, and I don't think most hiring committee members have strong opinions on the matter (while the ones who do don't always agree).

Comment: Though mathematics hiring committees might be thrown off if yours is the one application that isn't in Computer Modern :-)

Comment: @NateEldredge: But that may also be a positive effect as well, as it makes your application a bit more individual, less boring and better looking (given an appropriate font choice) than the others. There are some problems with Computer Modern, you know.

Comment: I would always go with at least 11 point type. "Bad eyesight" is an extremely common problem, and it only gets worse when someone has to read hundreds of job applications. Moreover, electronic job applications are  often printed on cheap laser printers by the receiving departments, which are particularly bad at small fonts.

Comment: What about Verdana or Calibri?

Comment: To me, a sans serif font would come across as a slightly unusual choice, but it wouldn't bother me (and I don't think either Verdana or Calibri would be a problem).